# SMTP server to smtp server forwarding?

Tags: email, email-server, smtp

we have one smtp server and we want incoming mail should store by smtp and forward two other smtp server is their any solution

we dont want email forwarding

Ex mail@mail.com to amail@mail.com

we want

Ex: mail@mail.com to mail@mail.com 
smtp server should deliver one copy to user and forward to other smtp server

Thankz in advance

Comment: What is server environment? Os, SMTP software?

Comment: postfix mail server we have...

Answer (score 0):

Server `A` ip = 192.168.1.1, server `B` ip = 192.168.2.1
One solution is to use [transport_maps](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html)
On server `A`
/etc/postfix/transport file contains: `*       smtp:[serverB.example.com]`
main.cf: `transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport`

And on server `B` in main.cf `mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.1.1 , 192.168.2.1, ...` (contains server `A` ip address)

Comment: The copy of mail should deliver to user on server A and same mail should be forword to other smtp

Example We have postfix server with bunch of users
what we want the mail should be deliverd to their postfix and same mail forworded to other smtp server like excange and all

Thankz for quick reply

Comment: for what purposes you need to forward to another smtp? Maybe you could try to store mail in database and then replicate database to other servers. And look [here](http://pjrlost.blogspot.com/2012/11/smtp-delivery-to-two-mail-servers-via.html)

Comment: Hii, currently we have one postfix server which handel all the mails of our organization now we are adding new microsoft exchange server so what we want when mail arrives by smtp at that moment smtp should delevier the mail to user as well as send that mail to other smtp that is microsoft and further he proceed......

Comment: Did you look in my provided link? You cannot export all accounts from postfix and import into exchange ? And then just relay mail from postfix to exchange...

Answer (score 0):

With postfix, use [recipient_bcc_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_bcc_maps). Eg

```
mail@mail.com mail@bcc.mail.com
```

In your transport maps, define where @bcc.mail.com should be delivered to. E.g.

```
bcc.mail.com smtp:[192.168.0.4]
```

If you want to get rid of the "bcc" in the domain name, you could probably just define the corresponding alias on 192.168.0.4.

Comment: Hii, currently we have one postfix server which handel all the mails of our organization now we are adding new microsoft exchange server so what we want when mail arrives by smtp at that moment smtp should delevier the mail to user as well as send that mail to other smtp that is microsoft and further he proceed......

Comment: Are you sure you are delivering to the clients via smtp? Seems a bit oldfashined to me. Nowadays, clients usually get their mail via imap. Anyway, as far as I know, exchange also has an imap interface, so you could just deliver all mail to exchange, and users could choose whether they want to connect via imap or exchange protocol. There is no real "deliver identical mail to two destinations" mechanism in postfix.